# Django - reverse not working and I don't know why

Tags: django

I've used `reverse` before and it's been fine. But now, I don't know why it's not working. It might be because I'm trying to `reverse` to a class based view and I've never done *that* before.

Here's my code -- where am I messing it up?

**views.py:**

```
class DocumentRequestDetail(NavMixin, TitleMixin, SelectedBrokerage, DetailView):
   model = DocumentRequest
   mod_nav = 'brokerage_nav.html'
   context_object_name = 'doc'
   subtitle = 'Document Request Details'


def MarkDocRequestComplete(request, bpk, pk):                                                    
   d = DocumentRequest.objects.get(pk= pk)                                                        
   d.is_complete = True                                                                            
   d.save()
   return reverse('doc_request_detail', args=[bpk, pk])  #<--- the offending line
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
  from django.views.generic.list import ListView
  from brokerage.views import *

  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/detail/$', BrokerageDetail.as_view(), name="brokerage_detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', BrokerageEdit.as_view(), name="brokerage_edit"),

    url(r'^(?P<bpk>[0-9]+)/doc-request/all/$', DocumentRequestList.as_view(), name="doc_request_list"),
    url(r'^(?P<bpk>[0-9]+)/doc-request/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', DocumentRequestDetail.as_view(), name="doc_request_detail"),

    url(r'^(?P<bpk>[0-9]+)/mark-doc-request-complete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', MarkDocRequestComplete, name="mark_doc_request_complete"),
  ]
```

**HTML Link that calls `MarkDocRequestComplete`:**

```
<a href="{% url 'brokerage:mark_doc_request_complete' brokerage.pk doc.pk %}" class='btn btn-lg btn-wide btn-success'>
<i class='ti-check'></i>
Mark Complete
</a>
```

**Error When Clicking HTML Link:**

```
Reverse for 'doc_request_detail' with arguments '(u'1', u'19')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I don't get it... what am I doing wrong?

**Edit** I should say that, in the error, the `1` and `19` are the correct values for `bpk` and `pk`.

**Edit 2** Added full URLs.py

Comment: Did you forget to restart the server after you updated `urls.py`?

Comment: I'm running on the built in development server (`python manage.py runserver`) so every time I save a file, it automatically restarts. It's not a production server, just a development server.

Comment: The problem I have it is that its not scanning your urls (it cannot find any pattern that matches, and it didn't try any either). Try restarting the server, and if that doesn't work - edit your question and post your entire `urls.py`.

Comment: I was thinking that too - it's not trying *any* url, so something is not right.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change:

```
return reverse('doc_request_detail', args=[bpk, pk])
```

to

```
return reverse('doc_request_detail', kwargs={'bpk': bpk, 'pk': pk})
```

---

You must also change your template tag from:

```
<a href="{% url 'brokerage:mark_doc_request_complete' brokerage.pk doc.pk %}" class='btn btn-lg btn-wide btn-success'>
```

to:

```
<a href="{% url 'brokerage:mark_doc_request_complete' bpk=brokerage.pk pk=doc.pk %}" class='btn btn-lg btn-wide btn-success'>
```

---

The reason for these changes is because you have names in your regular expression groups.

Comment: Same error: `Reverse for 'doc_request_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': u'19', 'bpk': u'1'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Comment: The change to the HTML code (Your edit) has similar results (same error). I don't think it's the HTML side, that's working. It's just the `reverse` that fails.

Comment: Can you try `"brokerage:doc_request_detail"` in your reverse?

Comment: I've tried that `brokerage:doc_request_detail` with the same result. It's crazy, since I've used `reverse` a lot in the past, but never to a CBV. It's one of those situations where it's so simple, but I don't get what I'm missing.

Comment: You can pass arguments for named capture groups as positional arguments. It's not necessary to use keyword arguments for reversing.

Answer (score -1):

The reason your url tag isn't working, is because you are namespacing it by adding `brokerage:` to it), when there is no namespace setup in your urls. See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) on how to properly setup namespaces.

The correct tag should be:

```
{% url 'mark_doc_request_complete' bpk=brokerage.pk pk=doc.pk %}
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I think that might be what @theamateurdataanalyst was getting at with this response. I have namespacing in use for all other `urls.py` (other apps) but hadn't done so yet for this app.